# Is there a WixBundleDirectoryLayout or a /layout sample snippet I can use?

Tags: wix, burn

There is a Burn Built-in Variable - WixBundleDirectoryLayout. How can I assign a value to this variable to change where the bundle extracts to?

I also tried running...

setup.exe /layout c:\temp

...from a command line and it just copies the setup.exe file to c:\temp, instead of actually extracting the bundle contents. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/layout` switch does not extract the contents of a Bundle. It downloads all the content and creates an image that you could then burn to DVD or put on a network share or whatever. That way the Bundle will not go download content in the future. If you have no uncompressed packages then the `/layout` switch just ends up copying the Bundle executable to the location you specify (or a no-op if you don't specify a different folder).