# How can I install .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 with WiX Burn?

Tags: windows, .net-3.5, wix, burn

The [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) manual includes "[How To: Install the .NET Framework Using Burn](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html)".  However, these instructions don't seem to work for installing .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, and later operating systems.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16616430/342581) and especially [this wix-users mailing list discussion](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Burn-Prerequisites-on-Windows-2012-Server-and-the-Server-Manager-requirement-td7583243.html) for details.  The [Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service pack 1 (Full Package) installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25150) won't run, because you need to use [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM.exe)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825236.aspx) or some other technique to enable the requested framework as a Windows feature.  A suggested command line is as follows, assuming Windows is installed in the default location:

```
C:\Windows\system32\dism.exe /online /norestart /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3
```

Is there a clean way to ensure that the .NET Framework 3.5 will be installed on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 with WiX?  Is there a good way to include such a step in the install chain?

Comment: Apparently, the 32-bit dism.exe is designed to fail immediately on 64-bit Windows (rather than forward on the command to the 64-bit version like, for example, procexp.exe does). So, to use dism, you have to find the 64-bit version on 64-bit Windows. %WINDIR%\sysnative\ works as the location on 64-bit Windows but not on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: @TomBlodget, thanks for the warning about using this approach on 32-bit systems.  I can confirm that this is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best I have been able to come up with.  I've added a fragment that that can install .NET Framework 3.5 for operating systems prior to Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.  Note that this requires a reference to NetFxExtension for the `NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL` definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <Fragment>
    <util:RegistrySearchRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL"/>    
    <PackageGroup Id="NetFx35Redist">
      <ExePackage
          SourceFile="{a path on my network}\Microsoft\DotNetFx\3.5\dotnetfx35.exe"
          DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Full"
          InstallCondition="VersionNT &lt; v6.1"
          InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
          RepairCommand="/q /norestart /f"
          UninstallCommand="/q /norestart /uninstall"
          PerMachine="yes"
          DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL &gt;= 1"
          Id="dotnetfx35.exe"
          Vital="yes"
          Permanent="yes"
          Protocol="none"
          Compressed="yes"
          Name="redist\dotnetfx35.exe">
        <!-- Exit codes
             0 = Successful installation.
          3010 = Successful installation; however, a system reboot is required.
        -->
        <ExitCode Value="0" Behavior="success" />
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
        <ExitCode Behavior="error"/>
      </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

In my managed bootstrapper code, I'm handling the Windows 8/Windows Server 2012 at the beginning of the Apply phase:

```
model.Bootstrapper.ApplyBegin += this.ApplyBegin;

...

private void ApplyBegin(object sender, ApplyBeginEventArgs e)
{
    this.EnsureNetFramework35();
}
```

The method that calls dism.exe to enable .NET Framework 3.5 follows.  Some of the code references classes like `ProgressViewModel` that won't be in every managed bootstrapper implementation, but I hope this provides a useful starting point for implementing your own version.

```
/// <summary>
/// Make sure we have the .NET Framework 3.5 when we're on Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, or later.
/// </summary>
private void EnsureNetFramework35()
{
    // Don't worry if we're on an older OS.  We don't need DISM.exe in that case.
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version < new Version(6, 1) && this.root.Model.Engine.NumericVariables.Contains("NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL"))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Don't worry if .NET Framework 3.5 is already installed.
    if (this.root.Model.Engine.NumericVariables.Contains("NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL") &&
        this.root.Model.Engine.NumericVariables["NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL"] >= 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Enable .NET Framework 3.5.
    this.root.Model.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Standard, "Enabling .NET Framework 3.5.");
    this.root.ProgressViewModel.Message = "Enabling .NET Framework 3.5.";

    // Get the path to DISM.exe.
    string windowsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
    string systemPath = Path.Combine(windowsPath, "System32");
    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
    {
        // For 32-bit processes on 64-bit systems, %windir%\system32 folder
        // can only be accessed by specifying %windir%\sysnative folder.
        systemPath = Path.Combine(windowsPath, "SysNative");
    }

    string dismPath = Path.Combine(systemPath, @"dism.exe");
    string arguments = "/online /enable-feature:NetFx3 /quiet /norestart";

    if (!File.Exists(dismPath))
    {
        this.root.Model.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Error, "Could not find file: " + dismPath);
        return;
    }

    this.root.Model.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Standard, dismPath + " " + arguments);
    this.root.ProgressViewModel.DetailMessage = dismPath + " " + arguments;

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = dismPath;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    // Check to see if we encountered any errors.
    if (process.ExitCode == 0)
    {
        this.root.Model.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Standard, ".NET Framework 3.5 enabled.");
        this.root.ProgressViewModel.Message = ".NET Framework 3.5 enabled.";
        this.root.ProgressViewModel.DetailMessage = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        this.root.Model.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Error, ".NET Framework 3.5 could not be enabled.  Exit code: " + process.ExitCode);
        this.root.ProgressViewModel.Message = ".NET Framework 3.5 could not be enabled.";
        this.root.ProgressViewModel.DetailMessage = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This how to install dot net using wix bootsrapper
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html

Comment: Thanks, @LeoN, but as I mentioned in the question, those instructions don't appear to work for Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.